"Reverse monotonicity" for k-Hessian measures
My question deals with the $k$-Hessian measure $\mu_k[u]$ of a $k$-convex function $u\in \Phi_k(\Omega)$ as defined in the articles "Hessian measures I-III" by N. S. Trudinger and X. J. Wang.
Let $u\leq v$ be two $k$-convex functions on an open and bounded domain $\Omega\subset \mathbb R^n$. Does it imply that $\mu_k[u] \leq \mu_k[v]$ on $\{u=v\}$?
I want to give some ideas around:

Trudinger and Wang proved the following "monotonicity lemma": If $u$ and $v$ be two $k$-convex functions coinciding on $\partial \Omega$ and $u \leq v$, then $\mu_k[u] \geq \mu_k[v]$.
The statement is simple to prove for $k=n$ being the space dimension of $\Omega$, where $\mu_k$ is the Monge‒Ampère measure. It is obvious that the subdifferential of $v$ includes the subdifferential of $u$ on $\{u=v\}$.
The statement is obvious if $u$ and $v$ are $C^2$ functions, because $D^2u\leq D^2v$ on $\{u=v\}$.
The statement is obvious in the interior of $\{u=v\}$.
If $\{u<v\}$ is compactly supported in $\Omega$, $u\leq v$ implies at least that $\mu_k[u]\left(\{u=v\}\right)\leq \mu_k[v]\left(\{u=v\}\right)$, because $\mu_k[u]\left(\Omega\right)=\mu_k[v]\left(\Omega\right)$ (because this depends only on the values around the boundary) and on $\{u<v\}$, we can apply the monotonicity lemma (see 1.)

